# How can I exploit parallelism when defining values in a sparse matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, parallel-processing, parfor

The following MATLAB code loops through all elements of a matrix with size 2*I*J x 2*I*J.

```
    for i=1:(I-2)
        for j=1:(J-2)
            ij1 = i*J+j+1; % row
            ij2 = i*J+j+1 + I*J; % col 
            D1(ij1,ij1) = 2;
            D1(ij1,ij2) = -1;
        end
    end
```

Is there any way I can parallelize it use MATLAB's [parfor](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/parfor.html) command? You can assume any element not defined is 0.  So this matrix ends up being sparse (mostly 0s).

Comment: What are the values of `I` and `J`? How long does this take to run? You can likely easily vectorize this, but I don’t think you can use parfor here.

Comment: If this takes so long that you need to improve the speed, you don't want to be creating a full matrix in the first place (or probably even a matrix at all). To efficiently make large sparse matrices like this use `spdiags`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo - I and J can be a couple hundred, anywhere between 200-300. How do I vectorize the above code and use spdiags to make it more efficient?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before using `parfor` it is recommended to read the guidelines related to [decide when to use parfor](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/decide-when-to-use-parfor.html). Specially this:

> Generally, if you want to make code run faster, first try to vectorize it.

Here vectorization can be used effectively to compute indices of the nonzero elements. Those indices are used in function [`sparse`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html). For it you need to define one of `i` or `j` to be a column vector and another a row vector. Implicit expansion takes effect and indices are computed.

```
I = 300;
J = 300;
i = (1:I-2).';
j = 1:J-2;
ij1 = i*J+j+1;
ij2 = i*J+j+1 + I*J;

D1 = sparse(ij1, ij1, 2, 2*I*J, 2*I*J) +  sparse(ij1, ij2, -1, 2*I*J, 2*I*J);
```

However for the comparison this can be a way of using `parfor` (not tested):

```
D1 = sparse (2*I*J, 2*I*J);
parfor i=1:(I-2)
    for j=1:(J-2)
        ij1 = i*J+j+1; 
        ij2 = i*J+j+1 + I*J;  
        D1 = D1 + sparse([ij1;ij1], [ij1;ij2], [2;-1], 2*I*J, 2*I*J) ;
    end
end
```

Here `D1` used as [reduction variable](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/reduction-variable.html).